# HTML input, allow autocomplete, but don't show the dropdown list when the input is first clicked

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I have an `input` HTML element of type `text`.  When I click into the input field, a list of suggestions pops up made up of the most recent inputs to that field before I even type anything into the field.

I know that I can block all autocomplete functionality with `autocomplete="off"` but I want to preserve the autocomplete functionality once the user starts typing.

The best example is a simple login form.

```html
<body>
  <form>
    Username<input name="username" type="text">
    Password<input name="password" type="password">
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

[image]

I can't find any references to this type of functionality on this forum or any other, but in my experience most fields on websites work this way.  The one idea I have is to change the `autocomplete` property using javascript when the user starts typing, but that seems very hacky.  I'm wondering if there is a less brute-force way to accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: Assertion: "_but in my experience most fields on websites work this way._" - can you provide a reference implementation (website) that demonstrates this capability? Assumption is any site that does this uses custom controls, not native input elements.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you're doing please?  html + js please

Comment: for simple things here is a video of how to create autocomplete with only CSS https://youtu.be/2h7BQYJRbys ... I don't know how important this functionality is for you... if only to help the user, the video is amazing because created by the king of CSS "KEVIN POWELL", also this w3school article https://w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp but if you want more you need some js added from this https://youtu.be/uFIl4BvYne0 (like adding keyup eventlisteners)

Comment: You could listen for [input events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). In your listener function, you might do something like `const myInput = event.target; if(myInput.value.length > 0){ myInput.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on"); }`. (There are some redundancies in this code, but hopefully you get the idea.)

Comment: Two points: 1. Your question title is not achievable with a native input alone. 2. I think what you are asking for is something along the lines of what you find as a search control on the MDN web site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: Added a code snippet and screenshot.  I totally understand if this isn't possible with plain HTML.  To clarify for Randy and Laaouatni, I am not looking for a suggestion-style autocomplete like for a search, I still want it to autofill with previous inputs to that input element.  I just don't want it to start suggesting until the user has typed something in the box.

Answer (score 1):

I use JavaScript, and the code is below

I also commented on all the code if you need it :)

also in HTML is best to use `<label>` because on click of the label, is automatically focused on the input

now I also added some `console.log();` if you want to test if this works

```js
// getting all the input available in the form
let myInput = document.querySelectorAll("input");
// for every input I will use the function inside
myInput.forEach(input => {
  // default, autocomplete will be disabled (because first time it will be empty)
  input.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
  // I will add event listener to every input, keyup is for when the key is pressed then released.

  input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    // getting what what <input> is typing now, so we can use it in the function
    const ActualInput = event.target;

    // if the length of the input is greater than 0, then we will be ON
    if (ActualInput.value.length > 0) {
      ActualInput.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
      console.log(ActualInput + " is ON"); // for debugging, delete later
    } // if the length of the input is 0, then we will be OFF and autocomplete will be disabled
    else {
      ActualInput.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
      console.log(ActualInput + " is OFF"); // for debugging, delete later
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <!-- username -->
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username">

    <!-- password -->
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password">

    <!-- submit -->
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```